# reshape the data （table）in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have data set as below,

```
myDat <- read.csv("http://mamajumder.github.io/data-science/data/reshape-source.csv")
kable(myDat)
```

want to reshape the data and produce the following output:

[image]

```
| player|variable |   A|   B|   C|
|------:|:--------|---:|---:|---:|
|      1|walking  | 408| 359| 359|
|      1|cycling  |  23|  45|  39|
|      2|walking  | 406| 386| 401|
|      2|cycling  |  43|  30|  46|
|      3|walking  | 418| 401| 392|
|      3|cycling  |  42|  45|  43|
```

and i use function `melt`, but still can not get the output. Is there any method available that can reshape the data set in the required format? Thanks

```
myDat1 <- melt(myDat,id='player')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that you can not get the output, you should share your attempts with us, in order for us to see what went wrong

```
library(reshape2)

m <- melt(myDat, id.vars = c("player", "track"), measure.vars = c("walking", "cycling"))
dcast(m, player + variable ~ track)
#  player variable   A   B   C
#1      1  walking 408 402 386
#2      1  cycling  43  31  41
#3      2  walking 373 404 422
#4      2  cycling  53  41  30
#5      3  walking 403 393 422
#6      3  cycling  25  46  48
```

Note that the output is not equal to your image.